# Alternatives to Sitemesh to help layout footers/headers in a Spring MVC app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, spring-mvc, single-page-application, sitemesh

In our current project we use sitemesh , But we are planning to change the UI in Bootstrap, Is there any alternative for sitemesh using Angular JS or using any new technologies ?

The reason for me to ask is , on each request the header and footer and the center page get reload, Any new technologies to avoid reloading the footer and header and only the center page reloads

Comment: I use bootstrap with Sitemesh in some projects (they are compatible) - is there any reason you cannot keep using sitemesh?

Comment: No ,The reason for me to ask is , on each request the header and footer and the center page get reload, Any new technologies to avoid reloading the footer and header and only the center page reloads

Comment: Yes there are ways of doing that but it has nothing to do with sitemesh or bootstrap... Instead, it has to do with how to design and develop your application.

Comment: Can you explain me the ways to do that please?

Comment: You can keep you header/footer (and overall structure of your site/app) in sitemesh.  When refreshing the page 'content' you then make ajax calls (undecorated by sitemesh). There are, literally, thousands of ways of achieving this but those tutorial-type questions are outside of the scope of this site